# Scraping with Python and BeautifulSoup, Something Wrong with Loop (Beginner)

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Something's wrong with my loop I think.  I'm getting all of the first day (there are several articles everyday), but then only 1 article for everyday after that.  Also, it just stops after a while before the loop is finished.  Can someone help diagnose the issue?  Here's what I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
import time

base_url = 'https://www.wsj.com/news/archive/'

startDate = date(2020, 1, 1)
endDate = date(2020, 5, 9)
delta = timedelta(days=1)


while startDate <= endDate:
    try:
        url_template = base_url + startDate.strftime("%Y%m%d")

        url = url_template
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})
        content = bs(response.content, "html.parser")
        headlines = content.find_all("h3")
        for headline in headlines:
            title = headline.find("a").text
            print(str(startDate) + ',"' + title + '"')
            time.sleep(10)
        startDate += delta
    except Exception as e:
        break
```

and here's my output when it stops on its own:

> > 2020-01-01,"Don Larsen, Who Threw the Only Perfect World Series Game, Dies at 90"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Corrections & Amplifications"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Poets Offer a Soulful, Spirited Start to the New Year"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Austrian Conservatives and Greens Form Coalition Government"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Bull Market Is Charging Into 2020"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Hospitals Merged. Quality Didn’t Improve."
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"David Stern, Former NBA Commissioner, Dies"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"‘Sonny’ Mehta, Editor in Chief of Book Publisher Knopf, Dies"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Buttigieg Campaign Raised $24.7 Million in Fourth Quarter"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Netanyahu Seeks Immunity From Israeli Corruption Charges"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"FDA to Ban All E-Cigarette Pod Flavors Except Tobacco and Menthol"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"In California, New Year Brings New Regulations for Businesses"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"‘The Longing for Less’ Review: Upscale Austerity"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Why Would Elizabeth Warren Want More Banks?"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"‘Hate Crime’ Is Only a Step Away From Thoughtcrime"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Latin America’s ‘Oasis’ Descends Into Chaos"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Google AI Beats Doctors at Breast Cancer Detection—Sometimes"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Can Tesla Hold Its Charge?"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Bankruptcy Court Rules Against PG&E Bondholders in Interest-Rate Fight"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Work & Family Mailbox: Sue Shellenbarger Answers Readers’ Questions"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Jobs and Inflation: The Great Trade-Off, Demystified"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"John Steinbeck’s Love Letters, Treasures Stashed in Storage Finally Get Unpacked"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Gertrude Himmelfarb"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Chuck Peddle’s $25 Microprocessor Ignited Computer Market"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Photos: Fire, Smoke and Havoc as Iraqis Rise Up Against U.S."
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Revelers Around the World Ring In 2020"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"2020 Vision: New Year, New Music"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Energy Producers Must Pay the Tab for Shale Drilling Bonanza"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"English Soccer Can’t Stop Talking About Armpits"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"China’s Monetary Policy Eases Into the New Year"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"‘We Were Freaking Out.’ Fire Season Death Toll Rises in Australia."
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"What to Know Before Resolving to Eat Less Meat"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"What’s News: Business & Finance"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"What’s News: World-Wide"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Yazidi Survivors Are Key to Bringing Islamic State Members to Justice"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Hong Kong Protesters Demand New Year’s Resolution"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Protesters Retreat From U.S. Embassy Site in Iraq"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"This Stock Exchange Only Trades on Mondays"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"North Korean Leader’s Warning Signals Tougher Diplomatic Slog"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Luxury Developers Turn the Page on Old Newspaper Headquarters"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Surging Amtrak Seeks Congress’s Green Light"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"The Songs Top Artists Had on Repeat in 2019"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Trump’s Tumultuous Year, From Policy Wins to Impeachment"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Lessons From Japan’s ‘Lost Decades’"
> >
> > 2020-01-01,"Don Larsen, Who Threw the Only Perfect World Series Game, Dies at 90"
> >
> > 2020-01-02,"Corrections & Amplifications"
> >
> > 2020-01-03,"Poets Offer a Soulful, Spirited Start to the New Year"
> >
> > 2020-01-04,"Austrian Conservatives and Greens Form Coalition Government"
> >
> > 2020-01-05,"Bull Market Is Charging Into 2020"
> >
> > 2020-01-06,"Hospitals Merged. Quality Didn’t Improve."
> >
> > 2020-01-07,"David Stern, Former NBA Commissioner, Dies"
> >
> > 2020-01-08,"‘Sonny’ Mehta, Editor in Chief of Book Publisher Knopf, Dies"
> >
> > 2020-01-09,"Buttigieg Campaign Raised $24.7 Million in Fourth Quarter"
> >
> > 2020-01-10,"Netanyahu Seeks Immunity From Israeli Corruption Charges"
> >
> > 2020-01-11,"FDA to Ban All E-Cigarette Pod Flavors Except Tobacco and Menthol"
> >
> > 2020-01-12,"In California, New Year Brings New Regulations for Businesses"
> >
> > 2020-01-13,"‘The Longing for Less’ Review: Upscale Austerity"
> >
> > 2020-01-14,"Why Would Elizabeth Warren Want More Banks?"
> >
> > 2020-01-15,"‘Hate Crime’ Is Only a Step Away From Thoughtcrime"
> >
> > 2020-01-16,"Latin America’s ‘Oasis’ Descends Into Chaos"
> >
> > 2020-01-17,"Google AI Beats Doctors at Breast Cancer Detection—Sometimes"
> >
> > 2020-01-18,"Can Tesla Hold Its Charge?"
> >
> > 2020-01-19,"Bankruptcy Court Rules Against PG&E Bondholders in Interest-Rate Fight"
> >
> > 2020-01-20,"Work & Family Mailbox: Sue Shellenbarger Answers Readers’ Questions"
> >
> > 2020-01-21,"Jobs and Inflation: The Great Trade-Off, Demystified"
> >
> > 2020-01-22,"John Steinbeck’s Love Letters, Treasures Stashed in Storage Finally Get Unpacked"
> >
> > 2020-01-23,"Gertrude Himmelfarb"
> >
> > 2020-01-24,"Chuck Peddle’s $25 Microprocessor Ignited Computer Market"
> >
> > 2020-01-25,"Photos: Fire, Smoke and Havoc as Iraqis Rise Up Against U.S."
> >
> > 2020-01-26,"Revelers Around the World Ring In 2020"
> >
> > 2020-01-27,"2020 Vision: New Year, New Music"
> >
> > 2020-01-28,"Energy Producers Must Pay the Tab for Shale Drilling Bonanza"
> >
> > 2020-01-29,"English Soccer Can’t Stop Talking About Armpits"
> >
> > 2020-01-30,"China’s Monetary Policy Eases Into the New Year"
> >
> > 2020-01-31,"‘We Were Freaking Out.’ Fire Season Death Toll Rises in Australia."
> >
> > 2020-02-01,"What to Know Before Resolving to Eat Less Meat"
> >
> > 2020-02-02,"What’s News: Business & Finance"
> >
> > 2020-02-03,"What’s News: World-Wide"
> >
> > 2020-02-04,"Yazidi Survivors Are Key to Bringing Islamic State Members to Justice"
> >
> > 2020-02-05,"Hong Kong Protesters Demand New Year’s Resolution"
> >
> > 2020-02-06,"Protesters Retreat From U.S. Embassy Site in Iraq"
> >
> > 2020-02-07,"This Stock Exchange Only Trades on Mondays"
> >
> > 2020-02-08,"North Korean Leader’s Warning Signals Tougher Diplomatic Slog"
> >
> > 2020-02-09,"Luxury Developers Turn the Page on Old Newspaper Headquarters"
> >
> > 2020-02-10,"Surging Amtrak Seeks Congress’s Green Light"
> >
> > 2020-02-11,"The Songs Top Artists Had on Repeat in 2019"
> >
> > 2020-02-12,"Trump’s Tumultuous Year, From Policy Wins to Impeachment"
> >
> > 2020-02-13,"Lessons From Japan’s ‘Lost Decades’"

Comment: The indentation of your break statement?

Comment: Plus the level at which you increment startDate seems a bit suspect to me. Do you really want to do that after each headline?

Comment: let me check, i reformatted it   for the post...ok on the actual code it has 8 spaces before

Comment: actually, no, i had it indented 1 tab less before, but i think there was a problem so i moved it up.  let me try again.  

sorry hold on it's gonna take a bit.  i lowered sleep to 1

Comment: Can you try putting the line with response = ... into a try/except block, where except only has next?

Comment: wait my bad, i redid the code part of the post.  i think it's accurate now.

okay and i just verified, so moving the increment out of the 2nd loop results in only the first day, then it stops

Comment: That would essentially simply retry if there wasn't a response and avoid hitting break too quickly.

Comment: ok i'll try that.  so you mean, put it in another loop?

Comment: No loop, just `try: \n response = ... \n except: \n next`. Oh man, typing on the phone isn't the best for SO...

Comment: while ... try:
     try:
        ....   
     try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers={....   
    except
        continue
like that?

ok. i think i see what you're saying.  why would it be hitting break though?

Comment: So, my point is: you are trying to get a response from a server, and if that doesn't happen, you immediately go to `break`. You could also try a few more times. Hence, that single line of code of yours with response = ..., insert a line above and two below.  Above with 'try:' and then indent properly and below you do except: and on the line below that next.

Comment: ok.  still running.  i'ill update in a few

Comment: well, it's still running, so maybe it worked?

Comment: still going....wish there was a way to output to terminal and file at the same time so i could seee what it's doing

Comment: ahh...it didn't write anything to the file.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i kind of got it to work using this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
import time
from time import sleep

base_url = 'https://www.wsj.com/news/archive/'

startDate = date(2016, 1, 1)
endDate = date(2020, 1, 4)
delta = timedelta(days=1)


while startDate <= endDate:
    try:
        url_template = base_url + startDate.strftime("%Y%m%d")

        url = url_template
        response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})
        content = bs(response.content, "html.parser")
        headlines = content.find_all("h3")
        for headline in headlines:
            title = headline.find("a").text
            print(str(startDate) + ',"' + title + '"')
    except Exception as e:
        startDate += delta
        sleep(2)
        continue
```

Comment: This may leave you with duplicates, though, as the start date isn't incremented when everything actually does work as intended.

Comment: yea, i tried the original version on a different site, and it works perfectly.  so the one directly above kinda worked because something was causing an error at the bottom of every page lol.  anyway, i actually think the wallstreet journal site interferes with scraping for some of the pages, so not sure i should stick with them.